# How to declare a global variable in php?

Tags: php, global-variables, global

I have code something like this:

```
<?
    $a="localhost";
    function body(){
        global $a;
        echo $a;
    }

    function head(){
        global $a;
        echo $a;
    }

    function footer(){
        global $a;
        echo $a;
    }
?>
```

is there any way to define the global variable in one place and make the variable `$a` accessible in all the functions at once? without making use of `global $a;` more?

Comment: No there isn't. If you don't like the `global` keyword, consider using the `$GLOBALS['a']` superglobal in all scopes, or consider passing the parameter to your functions.

Comment: If it's something important then even a session var can be used.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array can be used instead:

```
$GLOBALS['a'] = 'localhost';

function body(){

    echo $GLOBALS['a'];
}
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

---

If you have a set of functions that need some common variables, a class with properties may be a good choice instead of a global:

```
class MyTest
{
    protected $a;

    public function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function head()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }

    public function footer()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

$a = 'localhost';
$obj = new MyTest($a);
```

Comment: Warning: As of PHP 8.1.0, write access to the entire $GLOBALS array is no longer supported

Answer (score 89):

If the variable is not going to change you could use [`define`](http://php.net/define)

Example:

```
define('FOOTER_CONTENT', 'Hello I\'m an awesome footer!');

function footer()
{
    echo FOOTER_CONTENT;
}
```

Comment: What happens when `FOOTER_CONTENT` is attempted to modify? Is it just like `final` in Java or `const` in C, C++ and C#?

Comment: If you try to define FOOTER_CONTENT a second time, php will throw a notice about it

Comment: I needed to calculate the current unix epoch time each time a page is loaded, then use that value in a couple calculations (functions). "define" worked for me. Initially, I didn't see that "echo FOOTER_CONTENT;" didn't have a preceding '$' and I got errors.

Comment: If variable is not going to change its not a variable. Isn't it?!

Comment: Maybe in 2012, this was an acceptable answer, but using a `define()` for the content of the footer is not a good practice in today's php.

Comment: @istepaniuk Feel free to edit, I don't keep track of all my answers, especially when they're from 8 years ago.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks!  To be clear, [this does work on classes, too](https://ideone.com/VQZjAj).  And whoa, that's actually the constant I was going to define!

Answer (score 46):

If a variable is declared outside of a function its already in global scope. So there is no need to declare. But from where you calling this variable must have access to this variable. If you are calling from inside a function you have to use `global` keyword:

```
$variable = 5;

function name()
{
    global $variable;
    
    $value = $variable + 5;
    
    return $value;  
 
}
```

Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. If you want to include this file inside a function you can declare the variable as `global`.

```
// config.php

global $variable;

$variable = 5;
```

---

```
// other.php

function name()
{
    require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
}
```

You can use `$GLOBALS` as well. It's a superglobal so it has access everywhere.

```
$GLOBALS['variable'] = 5;

function name()
{
    echo $GLOBALS['variable'];
}
```

Depending on your choice you can choose either.

Comment: What if you use `function name() { global $variable; }` but the `$variable` has not been declared outside of the function? Is a "global" variable created by PHP? And can it be used from other functions later on?

Comment: Try it. It won't take more than 5 minutes. ;)

Comment: $_GLOBALS cannot be changed in user space anymore
(As of PHP 8.1.0, write access to the entire $GLOBALS array is no longer supported )

Answer (score 34):

Add your variables in $GLOBALS super global array like

```
$GLOBALS['variable'] = 'localhost';
```

and use it globally as

```
echo $GLOBALS['variable']
```

or you can use constant which are accessible throughout the script

```
define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
```

usage for define (NOTE - without the dollar)

```
echo HOSTNAME;
```

Comment: If you use 'define',once set, you can't change a define!

Comment: in your first example, it is saying that the '$variable is now called 'localhost' later in the script?

Comment: no if you want to use this variable you have to use it like $GLOBALS['variable'];

Comment: $_GLOBALS is no longer writable (As of PHP 8.1.0, write access to the entire $GLOBALS array is no longer supported: )

Answer (score 10):

This answer is very late but what I do is set a class that holds Booleans, arrays, and integer-initial values as global scope static variables. Any constant strings are defined as such.

```
define("myconstant", "value"); 

class globalVars {

    static $a = false;

    static $b = 0;

    static $c = array('first' => 2, 'second' => 5);

}


function test($num) {

    if (!globalVars::$a) {

        $returnVal = 'The ' . myconstant . ' of ' . $num . ' plus ' . globalVars::$b . ' plus ' . globalVars::$c['second'] . ' is ' . ($num + globalVars::$b + globalVars::$c['second']) . '.';

        globalVars::$a = true;

    } else {

        $returnVal = 'I forgot';

    }

    return $returnVal;

}

echo test(9); ---> The value of 9 + 0 + 5 is 14.

echo "<br>";

echo globalVars::$a; ----> 1
```

The `static` keywords must be present in the class else the vars $a, $b, and $c will not be globally scoped.

Comment: This is a good solution for many reasons. Class static requires just a few characters added to the basic variable name:  G::$Name, where the declaration looks like this: class G { static $Name, $Name2;} Note that G can be truly global variables, then E could be used for variables relating to Employees. This is easier to program with than the full-scale object-oriented paradigm supported by PHP. If constants are truly needed, you can declare them after "const" just like the variables declared after "static"--just leave out the dollar signs.  G::Example would be an example of a global constant.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the keyword `use` in **Closure** functions or **Lambdas** if this fits your intention... PHP 7.0 though. Not that's its better, but just an alternative.

```
$foo = "New";
$closure = (function($bar) use ($foo) {
    echo "$foo $bar";
})("York");
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/VqOFK) | 
[info](http://culttt.com/2013/03/25/what-are-php-lambdas-and-closures/)

Answer (score 8):

You can declare global variables as static attributes:

```
class global {
    static $foo = "bar";
}
```

And you can use and modify it **every where** you like, like:

```
function echoFoo() {
    echo global::$foo;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You answered this in the way you wrote the question - use 'define'. but once set, you can't change a define.

Alternatively, there are tricks with a constant in a class, such as class::constant that you can use. You can also make them variable by declaring static properties to the class, with functions to set the static property if you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make use of procedural function instead of variable and call them any where as you.

I usually make a collection of configuration values and put them inside a function with return statement. I just include that where I need to make use of global value and call particular function.

```
function host()
{
   return "localhost";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`$GLOBALS[]` **is** the right solution, but since we're talking about alternatives, a function can also do this job easily:

```
function capital() {
    return my_var() . ' is the capital of Italy';
}

function my_var() {
    return 'Rome';
}
```

Comment: Here the function is not A global variable.

Comment: @PratikSoni I never said it was a global variable. Next time read better, that way you won't spread negative ratings everywhere.

Comment: I am sorry if you think this ie misleading. But i was going in context of actual question. And the answer is not even little bit near by to the question. "How to declare a global variable in php?"