# Can not access global variable outside function

Tags: php, sql

I've got two isset function

```
function getPlayers(){
if (isset($_POST['select'])) 
{
    global $t1select;
    global $t2select;
```

The code above is part of the first function, notice the two global variables I declared, I did this because I would like to use them in my second functions:

```
function PlayerAttributes(){
if (isset($_POST['teamselect'])) {
```

The function above is my second function.

**The Problem**

When I try to refer to the global variables in the second function, I get the error message  "Undefined variable: t1select "

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `global $var` in *every* function you wish to use them in, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Varibles should be declared as `global` in every function that is going to use them. Otherwise they will be only for the local scope of the function.

Another approach is to use the `$GLOBALS['varname']` syntax. This will work without any declarations.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. The error is not showing up anymore, but  nothing gets displayed. When I do a var_dump on the variable it returns null, however when I do a var_dump on the variable without declaring it as a global I get the correct contents, any idea what going on here?

Comment: I notice you declare the global variables after some `if` statement - in this case the variable will not be `global` in statements before the declaration.