# Passing values in php

Tags: php

I'm writing a project with two php code blocks.  How do I send a value of a variable from one php block to the other?

```
<?php

function display() {
    $items = array(
        '<a href="?item=cherry">  <img src= "img/cherries.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="cherry"/></a>',
        '<a href="?item=cherry">  <img src= "img/cherries.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="cherry"/></a>',
        '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
        '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>'
    );





    $num1 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
    $num2 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
    $num3 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
    echo $num1;

    echo $num2;


    echo $num3;
}

display();
?>

<td align="left"><input type="text" name="credit" value="<?php
    if (isset($_POST['spin'])) {
        $t = $_POST['bet'];
        $v = $_POST['credit'];
        if($v >=0){
            if ($t > $v) {
                if ($num1 == "cherry" && $num2 == "cherry" && $num3 == "cherry"):
                    $v = $v + $t + 100;
                endif;
                if ($num1 == "lemon" && $num2 == "lemon" && $num3 == "lemon"):
                    $v = $v + $t + 10;
                endif;
                if ($num1 == "star" && $num2 == "star" && $num3 == "star"):
                    $v = $v + $t + 20;
                endif;
                if ($num1 == "bar" && $num2 == "bar" && $num3 == "bar"):
                    $v = $v + $t + 50;
                endif;
                $totalCredit = $v;
            } else {
                $totalCredit = ($v - $t);
            }
        }else{
            $totalCredit = 0;
        }
    }
    echo (isset($totalCredit)) ? $totalCredit : '100';
?>" readonly="true"id="credit"/></td>
```

I want to pass the value of num1 2 and 3 to the above php code block.  How would I go about doing this>?

Comment: By declaring your variables global. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php) link.

Comment: Your three HTML-ladden variables are not going to compare well against `=="cherry"` anyway. Maybe you'd want that display function only do the HTML wrapping, not the randomization; and perhaps call it individually for each $num.

Comment: I was just about to comment on that. Or instead of using @mario's suggestion, you could use other functions such as `strstr` or `strpos`

Comment: @mario  New programmer here um Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: `$num1` doesn't just contain things like "cherry" or "lemon" It's going to have that whole HTML string in which you assigned it.

Answer (score 4):

The function should return something:

```
return array($num1, $num2, $num3);
```

The second code block can then receive them in its own variables:

```
list ($num1, $num2, $num3) = display();
```