# php oops including another page

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code in database.php

```
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "ss";
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', $db_username, $db_pass);
```

In my class page

```
include_once "database.php";
class article_fun
{
  public function myfun()
    {
     $sqlcreate = $con->query("selct query")
     }
}
```

How do we do we use `$con->query("select query")` getting an error `Undefined variable: con` how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
class article_fun
{
private $con;
public function __construct($con){
$this->con=$con;
}
  public function myfun()
    {
     $sqlcreate = $this->con->query("selct query")
     }
}
```

call this

```
include_once "database.php";

new article_fun($con);
```

or use this

```
class article_fun
    {
    private $con;
    public function __construct(){
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "ss";
    $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', $db_username, $db_pass);
    }
      public function myfun()
        {
         $sqlcreate = $this->con->query("selct query")
         }
    }
```

Comment: iam getting an error `Warning: Missing argument 1 for article_fun::__construct(), called in`

Comment: iam using ur first method

Comment: as a parameters to class?

Comment: call this        include_once "database.php";
    
       new article_fun($con);

Answer (score 1):

Pass`$con` as a parameter to `article_fun::myFun()`

```
class article_fun
{
  public function myfun($con)
  {
     $sqlcreate = $con->query("selct query")
  }
}
```

FYI, in PHP it is convention to start class names with a capital letter and use camelCase:

```
class ArticleFun
```

Comment: cant we pass it to constructor?? and use the same in all other functions of same class??

Answer (score 1):

Your created variables are outside of the function scope.
So you can't access variables outside a function from inside the function.
Try to use the magic function `__construct()`
Like this:

```
class article_fun{
  private $_con;

  public function __construct( $con ){
    $this -> _con = $con;
  };

  public function myfun(){
    $sqlcreate = $this -> _con->query("selct query")
  }
}
```

Now you just have to pass the `$con`var to the Class like so:

```
$article_fun = new article_fun( $con );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class article_fun
{
  public function myfun()
  {
     global $con;
     $sqlcreate = $con->query("select query")
  }
}
```

Your variable is definied in the global context and you try to use it in a method of a class.

Comment: Don't use `global`. That's a bad practice.

Comment: It was the better solution. If we can demonstrate the proper way to do something we should. Otherwise newbies learn bad habits that are hard to break.

Comment: @andreashager but what if i want to use in other function of the same class?? again i have to define global in other function also?

Comment: @user3436481 see fox's answer for the conventional solution to this question

Answer (score -1):

Use global variable

```
  $GLOBALS['con'] = $yourConnection;
```

Check this link for answer
[How to declare a global variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Comment: This is a *very* bad practice