# How to access data from other .php file in PHP?

Tags: php, include, require, data-access

I have `login.php` and `mainpage.php` files and I want to access `login.php`'s user's data from `mainpage.php`.

Should I use `require` or `include`? How to connect those files?

```
require login.php;
include login.php;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best would be to write object-oriented codes, i.e. `mainpage.php` would

```
require('login.php');
```

just to get definition of let's say `class LoginForm` and then in `mainpage.php` you would do:

```
$loginForm = new LoginForm();
```

Alternatively you could place your logic into functions and let `mainpage.php` call something like `handleLogin()` defined in `login.php`. In both of mentioned cases `mainpage.php` just needs to know the definition of function/class, therefore you should use `require` or `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your data into $GLOBALS.

You can check great examples here
[How to declare a global variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Comment: a more specific answer would be much more helpful