# Apache2.2-PHP include from root folder

Tags: php, html

I currently learning HTML, JS and PHP all at the same time (cus why not?)

And implementing the header.html in PHP is not so fun.

It works on the main page or "index.php" by just adding:

```
<?php include("header.html");?>ex.php
```

And then the other pages by adding:

```
<?php include("../header.html");?>ex.php
```

But after a while you forget how many "../../../" you need to put in, in order to get to root of the server folder. Is there a way to get to root of webserver easily? simply "/header.html" is not working out.

any ideas?

Solution?:

My current solution is simple to set the header path as

```
/home/yuannan/Web/header.html
```

Or where your file is from the ROOT OF THE SERVER and not the web server

Comment: what happens if you just try `include("header.html");` just like in index.php?

Comment: header doesn't appear, as i guess the server is trying to look for header.php within it's current folder.

which could be miles deep from with the root folder as my website has everything from memes to rant to even help with basic BASH. This is why "../../../" will be massive problem for me as most pages are within a deep nested folder and will be a headache to keep track

Comment: 1. it is not really possible to reliably find the "root" folder of a web application. 2. this is typically solved by a central configuration 3. using typical MVC frameworks this question does not really arise that much.

Comment: if that is the case, i would suggest you to declare a global variable with the base address as its value and then call the required file as for eg, `<?php include(base_href."header.html");?>` where `base_href` will have the root folder

Comment: and where would I declare that?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530536/3168859) helps

Comment: hmmmm, I'll master HTML first and then move onto PHP. Guess this  is too much for my fragile young brain. :/

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is:

1. Use a standard location for my php "library" files (lets say [project_path]/lib/php/)
2. Create a helper file "setpath.php" which is going to set the correct PHP path(s). In this file I work with relevant paths which are webroot independent:

   ```
   function setPath() {
       // get the path to the root folder of the 
       // project using our current known location
       $bn = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

       // Get absolute path
       $bn=realpath($bn)."/";

       // Extend with all needed paths (few examples)
       $new_paths = $bn.PATH_SEPARATOR."$bn/db".PATH_SEPARATOR."$bn/templates";

       // Set the environment
       set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $new_paths);
   }
   ```
3. Now each file needs to know how to include this and call `setPath()`, so from your index this is `include("lib/php/setpath.php")` and from your lib/php/db this would be `include("../setpath.php")`.
4. You are now good to include any file which is in the registered paths without knowing its excact location

Additionally, I have found out that using [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) can save you lots of effort trying to figure out dependencies manually...

Finally, in some cases knowing the server webroot is needed. In these cases I use something like the following (also in my lib/php/ folder) which provides the file-system path and the webroot of the project as GLOBAL variables (... some may say bad practice ...)

```
// Fix document root to work with mod_alias (that maybe buggy)
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

// The root of the project in the Document 
$SRV['BASEDIR'] = substr( __FILE__,0, strrpos(__FILE__, "/lib"));
$SRV['WEBROOT'] = substr( __FILE__,0, strrpos(__FILE__, "/lib"));
$SRV['WEBROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"",$SRV['WEBROOT']);
```

I use the above tools along with some Autoloaders as the base of my projects. Hope that helps you or inspires someone to provide a better solution.

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for my website is simply set a general filepath and then use that throughout the website just below the `<body>` tag. Pretty simple and straightforward. Just make sure your `$Filepath` points to wherever you have your header file stored, it'll mitigate the issue of having to use backticks for each file layer. Like so:

```
    <?php
        {
        $Filepath= "c:/wamp/www/";
        include ("{$Filepath}header.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Apache 2.4.7 so will  I have to set it to
        $Filepath="/home/yuannan/Web"

or where my files are from the "root" of the machine and not the server?

Comment: It should be the file path of where the files are located on the server. So it should be $filepath="/home/yuannan/web". If not, try the path from the root of the machine.

Comment: I'm on windows using WAMP so it may be slightly different.