# Using global array on php multipage form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to create a php multipage form, but i can't use $_SESSION variables to save and reuse data when i'm changing pages.

I've tought to use a personal global array (eg. GLOBAL $data; $data = array();) where i'll put my field variables, but when i go back through pages (eg. from pag 2 to pag 1), array $data is empty.

Where i've done wrong?

Comment: you can't do it without using session variables.. you can use tabs, without refreshing the page..

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables by below ways:-

**Global variables:-**

```
$GLOBALS['variable'] = 'value';
// use them globally
```

**Static variables:-**

```
define('VARIABLE_NAME', 'value');
// static only. value is not changable
```

**Session variables:-**

```
session_start(); // need to define below line
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'value';
```

If you need to change variables value by page to page then you should use [SESSION](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm).

Check this link for [GLOBAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php) variables.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use keyword GLOBAL while accessing data. for example on

```
page 1

$data = array("a", "b");

on page 2

global $data;
print_r($data);
```