# PHP access variable declared in function outside

Tags: php, variables, global, superglobals, scopes

i am new in PHP and i had a question: how can i access a variable declared in a function from global scope?

```
function test(){
   $x = 6;
   $y = 5;
   return $x;   
}

test();
echo $GLOBALS['y'];
```

I want to access variable y in global.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Either use `$GLOBALS['y']` in the function (it's super-global, so it's available anywhere) or define `global $y;` in the beginning of the function.

Note: using such global variables is a bad style, better return the value (or modify it by passing it as a by-reference parameter to the function)