# How Do I Get This PHP Working?

Tags: php

I was hoping the below would print

```
live
got here
```

Instead it prints

```
got here
```

The code:

```
$config['env'] = 'live';

sayEnvironment();

function sayEnvironment () {

  echo $config['env'];
  echo 'got here';

}
```

How do I set this global variable and have everything inside a function access it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Comment: Globals are generally not a good sign. A constant might make more sense for this, since I'm assuming the environment won't change at run-time. There are details in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `global` to use global variables inside functions:

```
$config['env'] = 'live';

sayEnvironment();

function sayEnvironment () {
  global $config;
  echo $config['env'];
  echo 'got here';
}
```

Or if you have anonymous function, you can use `use`:

```
$sayEnvironment2 = function () use ($config) {
    echo $config['env'];
    echo 'got here';
};

$sayEnvironment2(); // must be called AFTER php parser has seen actual function.
```

[Sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f7bac5beae6264bb4ed26e1448b813be3198d1c)

Comment: That doesn't work it says syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'

Comment: @Exitos Sorry, missed anonymous function context.

Answer (score 1):

here you go,

```
$config['env'] = 'live';

sayEnvironment();

function sayEnvironment () {
global $config;
  echo  $config['env'];
  echo 'got here';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use PHP `$GLOBALS` for this:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['config']['env'] = 'live';

sayEnvironment();

function sayEnvironment () {
  echo $GLOBALS['config']['env'];
  echo 'got here';

}
```

It's not really considered a good practise to do the above though, but without knowing what you're aiming for it's hard to advise another method. Usually some form of dependency injection would be better.

Docs for it: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php