# Variable not working under function in PHP, even if the variable is global

Tags: php, global

I try to define variable and then call it in my function, and then i call the function in another file. So, the variables outside the function work properly, but when i call them in function they don't work. Here's the code.

```
$info = new ServerInfo($server->GetServerData('IPAdress'));
$id = $server->GetServerData('ID');
$sshhost = $server->GetServerData('SSHHOST');
$sshport = $server->GetServerData('SSHPORT');
$sshuser = $server->GetServerData('SSHUSER');
$sshpw = base64_decode(base64_decode($server->GetServerData('SSHPW')));
$port = $server->GetServerData('PORT');

/* Start Server Function */
function start_server($sshhost, $sshport, $sshuser, $sshpw){

global $sshhost;
global $sshport;
global $sshuser;
global $sshpw;
global $id;
global $port;

if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) return "SSH2 PHP extenzija nije instalirana";

if(!($con = ssh2_connect($sshhost, $sshport))){
    return "Ne mogu se spojiti na server";
} else {

    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $sshuser, $sshpw)) {
        return "Netačni podatci za prijavu";
    } else {

        $stream = ssh2_shell($con, 'vt102', null, 80, 24, SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS);
        fwrite( $stream, "cd /home/cs && screen -A -m -S srv".$id. " ./hlds_run -console -game cstrike +port " .$port. " +map de_dust2 +maxplayers 32 -pingboost 1".PHP_EOL);
        sleep(1);
        echo "Server Startovan";

        return TRUE;

    }
}   
}
```

Comment: You're passing them as arguments *and* declaring them global. Do one or the other. (Preferably, as arguments.)

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you have the function parameters named the same as the variables. Try not using Global variables if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare them using `$GLOBALS['variablename']` then still use the `$variablename` in other function.
ref:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp
[How to declare a global variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

```
function start_server($sshhost, $sshport, $sshuser, $sshpw){

$GLOBALS['sshhost'] = $sshhost;
$GLOBALS['sshport'] = $sshport;
$GLOBALS['sshuser'] = $sshuser;
$GLOBALS['sshpw'] = $sshpw;

/* do more stuff */
```