# create global variables from column names and row values

Tags: php

table `clients` has 29 columns.

as an example, wi'll take five of them:

`earth, sun, moon, jupiter, venus`

row `id=1` has the following values:

`blue, gold, silver, lessons, arts`

```
function giveme_vars($id){
    global $db;
    $sql = "select * from clients where id = :aid";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":aid" => $id
    ]);
    $row = $st->fetch();
    // here I need something like this:  
    foreach($row as $key=>$val){
        $variable_key = $row_value;
        //then make all of them global;
    }
}
```

As a result I'm expecting:

```
$earth = 'blue';
$sun = 'gold';
$mon = 'silver';
$jupiter = 'lessons';
$venus = 'arts';
```

All of the variables should be `global` i.e. accessible for all files on the server.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php)

Comment: You would be better off storing these values as an associative array rather than individual variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using braces with dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/using-braces-with-dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Like your first commentor pointed out: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530465/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php) post clarifies it

```
 class global{
        static $variable= "something";
    }
```

access and use:

```
function dosomething(){
    echo global::$var;
}
```

Comment: @qadenza. well yea ofc... maybe just try to be cooperative and use $GLOBALS["sun"] so you dont have to make 29 different global variables yourself.

Comment: I tried, but `$GLOBALS['sun']` is not accessible in another php file.